# MySQL internal date to datetime convertion. PHP (Zend Framework 1.11) as middleware

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, php-5.2

So I am wondering If I've encountered a gotcha which should be more or less obvious.

So lets say we have a DB field called `dateField` which is in datetime. Lets also assume that all records in the table have this value there: `2013-10-15 13:15:46`.

Now we would like to extract records in a date range. We use 2013-10-15 (`yyyy-mm-dd`) format in the web site front-end. (No, SQL Injection is NOT possible. It goes through a PDO. :D)

Lets also assume that the select's where statement is inserted like this:
$select->where('dateField >= ?', $dateFrom);
$select->where('dateField <= ?', $dateTo);

So when we have a range like this:

***From:** 2013-10-10 **To:** 2013-10-16* everything is OK.

But with an expression like this:
***From:*** 2013-10-15 **To:** 2013-10-15 it shows no results! :D

I am guessing that MySQL **internally converts** my date type *2013-10-15* to *2013-10-15 00:00:00*  and my WHERE clause becomes:

```
SELECT .... WHERE dateField <= 2013-10-15 00:00:00 AND dateField >= 2013-10-15 00:00:00;
```

Of course in this case *2013-10-15 13:15:46* is NOT in my WHERE clause. :D :D

I've already fixed this via comparing only the date part of the :

```
$select->where('DATE(dateField) >= ?', $dateFrom);
$select->where('DATE(dateField) <= ?', $dateTo);
```

But my questions are:

Can anyone explain a bit more about the MySQL internal date/datetime conversions (low level oprations)?

Does this question qualify as an good addition to the community wiki?

Answer (score 1):

If the time part is not set, then casting such DATE to DATETIME/TIMESTAMP will cause filling it's time part as `00:00:00` - this is a normal behavior (like described [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestamp)).

To get it works - you'll need specify your time part explicit `2013-10-15 00:00:00` till `2013-10-15 23:59:59`